# Как проще всего получить доступ к сайту на localhost из Интернета?

Tags: localhost

Собственно сабж. Нужно выложить сайт, который находится на компьютере, на localhost, в Интернет, чтобы заказчик смог его посмотреть. Возможно кто-то сталкивался с такой задачей и сможет помочь.

Comment: На ХабраХабре как-то видел статью, а сейчас не могу найти...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ппосмотри описание dyndns. Если через домашний роутер, то настрой на нем проброс (опция разрешить доступ из инета). Если через vpn, то нужно чтобы заказчик был в том же адресном пространстве. Если временный статический из пула провайдера, то сообщаешь клиенту свой айпи.

Answer (score 2):

Если у Вас статический IP, то вы и так можете это сделать.
Если нет, то уточните у Вашего провайдера, предоставляет ли он такую услугу.

Comment: Нет, IP динамический, но я могу взять статический IP.

Comment: Не важно статический IP или нет. Важно что бы он был *внешним*, т.е. что бы  за ним не было никаких [NAT-маршрутизаторов](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT). Ну и фаирволов, само собой.